# Type inference failed in Kotlin using PairList

Tags: android, kotlin

```
lateinit var dataList: PairList<Car, People>
```

I want to retrieve specific position based on pair, so what I do is:

```
val pair = Pair(carObj, peopleObj)
val position = dataList.indexOf(pair as Pair<Car, People>)
```

But it give me an error of Type inference failed and asks me to explicitly show type. I think I've done it with `as Pair<Car, People>`, but it says that it's a redundant statement. Any ideas on where I went totally wrong? :)

PairList class:

```
public class PairList<F, S> extends ArrayList<Pair<F, S>> {

public boolean add(F first, S second) {
    return add(new Pair<>(first, second));
}

public void add(int index, F first, S second) {
    add(index, new Pair<>(first, second));
}

@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Pair) {
        return super.indexOf(o);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            Pair<F, S> pair = get(i);
            if (pair != null) {
                if (pair.first.equals(o)) return i;
            } else {
                if (o == null) return i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            Pair<F, S> pair = get(i);
            if (pair != null) {
                if (pair.second.equals(o)) return i;
            } else {
                if (o == null) return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public int indexOf(F first, S second) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        Pair<F, S> pair = get(i);
        if (pair != null) {
            if (pair.first.equals(first) && pair.second.equals(second)) {
                return i;
            }
        } else {
            if(first == null && second == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What's a `PairList<Car, People>`? Just a `List<Pair<Car, People>>`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes.

Comment: Is PairList your custom class?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Provide an MVCE.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi Yes, forgot to mentioned that. I updated post with additional code.

Comment: Please note that there are types erasure on JVM. Technically, the cast to `Pair<Car,People>` will be compiled to the JVM bytecode as the cast to `Pair<*,*>` (where * means upper bound type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PairList class is probably extending Pair class from `android.util.Pair;` and when you are using that in your kotlin file it is using `kotlin.Pair`. Caz of this you are getting Type inference failed. 
To overcome this you have two solution

1. simply turn your java file to kotlin
2. use Pair class in kotlin using import `android.util.Pair`.
   val pair = android.util.Pair(carObj, peopleObj)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `android.util.Pair` in `PairList.java` and you created `Pair(carObj, peopleObj)` using `kotlin.Pair;`

So replace `android.util.Pair;` with `import kotlin.Pair;` in `PairList.java` everything will work.

Comment: while your answer is correct. For using kotlin.Pair in the java file, he needs to change other things too. like then he will not be able to use `pair.first` he has to change it to `pair.getFirst()`. You will not be able to use variables directly, So  it will be better to turn that file to kotlin, or use android Pair in his kotlin file.

Comment: Yeah better to turn it to Kotlin file and then use ``kotlin.Pair`` instead of `android.util.Pair`

Comment: Yes, correct. But he has to check that is it convenient for him to turn that file from java or not.

Comment: Yeah why i recommend ``kotlin.Pair`` is, it will be independent of Android platform

Comment: Yes and I also recommend to use that only, but if only this file is in java then it should be converted to kotlin otherwise it's better to check with the project as well before converting it.